# I get a message of ttf mscorefonts failure to install

Tags: updates

/home/asaruhu/Pictures/Screenshot from 2016-11-15 13:46:01.png
this is what happens when i attempt to install the restricted extras: the terminal loads various sourceforge documents of different fonts and then suddenly stops and closes. The message comes back after a while asking me to install the same programs

Comment: I think this is caused by slow Internet connection, you can skip it safely and try again later to install the restricted extras.

Comment: You didn't actually upload any picture. You need to click on the little image button in the editor toolbar and either 1) drag it into the shown area or 2) click on that area to navigate to and select the image file.

Comment: Also, could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Search on 'Microsoft EULA" you have to agree before fonts will install. That might be your problem since you didn't mention it.